# Aggregate using LINQ with Query Expression syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

**EDIT: I have completely wiped out my initial question to reformulate it in way that is more straight forward. I'm sorry if that's against any etiquette, but I thought it would be even worse to post a new one on the same topic :)**

Is it possible to write this LINQ-query with query comprehension syntax by implementing your own SelectMany or the like:

```
var enumerable = 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
              .Aggregate(new SomeAggregation(),
                         (c, n) =>
                         {
                             var l = c.SomeOperation(); // expensive operation
                             return c.UseIt(l).UseItAgain(l); // the result is needed multiple times
                         });
```

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
var enumerable = from c in new SomeAggregation().AsSeed()
                 from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                 from l in c.SomeOperation()
                 select c.UseIt(l).UseItAgain(l);
```

Or:

```
var enumerable = from c in new SomeAggregation().AsSeed()
                 from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                 let l = c.SomeOperation()
                 select c.UseIt(l).UseItAgain(l);
```

Any help, hints, links or the like is highly appreciated!

Comment: maybe post an example of the LINQ you would want to write?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I've updated it now :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, since `let` just evaluates to a call to `Select`, that this should work if you implement a LINQ-style `Select` method, similar to the `SelectMany` method you implemented already, only simpler. I may be missing something, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried that, but the problem is the transformation func in Select() only takes one argument, thus I cannot sent in the aggregator. Now the aggregator is there, its just wrapped in an anonymous type that is not the same type as the one we want to return. And I can't see how to get past this type mismatch.

Comment: @asgerhallas: I don't entirely understand what you're hoping to make it do. Can you provide details on how you would expect `let` to behave in this case?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I have provided details and resulting behavior of the usage of let now :)